# Magento 2 - Get value of date attribute

Tags: attributes, product, magento2

I've created an attribute which is a date, how would I get the value to display on the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have checked in default luma theme  on below file path

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product
```

On the product listing page , we have check inside foreach loop under product name-

you can get custom date attribute value like that-

```
$_product->getCustomattributecode();
```

where "customattributecode" is your date type attribute code.